# Homebrew: How do I install PHPUnit 6.5?

Tags: phpunit, homebrew

I'm trying to install php unit version 6.5.

I already have 7.0.1 install and I have attempted to install phpunit versions 6.5 with:

```
brew install phpunit@6.5
```

Brew tells me that the older version is installed but `phpunit --version` is 7.0.1.

Trying `brew switch phpunit 6.5`, I get the message:

```
Error: phpunit does not have a version "6.5" in the Cellar.
Versions available: 7.0.1
```

What steps do I need to take to switch versions to 6.5?

Comment: What worked for you ?

Comment: I ended up doing a manual install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If I am not mistaking, this is because the current version is [6.5.6](http://formulae.brew.sh/formula/phpunit@6.5) and not just 6.5
2. If this fails, maybe try doing a manual install from their archived package, instructions can be found [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html)
3. If you still don't succeed, you could also try with composer to manage your project packages

Comment: Neither `brew install phpunit@6.5.6` or `brew switch phpunit 6.5.6` work.

Comment: `Error: phpunit does not have a version "6.5.6" in the Cellar.
Versions available: 7.0.1`

Comment: Unfortunately, my only mac is dead, so I can't check, but i've updated my answer, check if this works for you

Answer (score 5):

I've installed manually:

```
$ wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-6.5.phar
$ chmod +x phpunit-6.5.phar
$ sudo mv phpunit-6.5.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
$ phpunit --version
```